# Make apache send a false SERVER_NAME to PHP

Tags: php, apache

Does anyone know if there's a way to send PHP a different `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` value to the one that's actually being used to call Apache? I.E: if the user types `dev.mydomain.com` in the URL bar of the browser, it arrives at the correct IP address, but tells PHP that the server name is `live.mydomain.com`? I've Googled around for this, but not found anything.

**"Why do I want to do this?" I hear you ask**

I've inherited a large PHP system that makes a lot of decisions based on the domain name being used to call the system. The domain name is sometimes hardcoded, and sometimes stored in the database.

I now need to make a development environment separate from the live environment. I could search and replace all those domain names, but I then have different code for the two environments, and problems with the code versioning.

**Please note**

I don't need the user to hack or fake anything, so there's no security issues. I want, as the site administrator, Apache and PHP to use different domain names.

**The following 'solutions' are not what I'm asking**

*ServerAlias* : No. Apache still sends the wrong domain name to the code.

*Redirecting* : Is only going to send the request to the wrong server.

*Hacking the client's host file* : Sure I can do that on my own machine, but a number of 'technically naive' people without administrator rights on their machines also need to test the development site. And they would need to remember to change it back when done tesing. It would become unworkable.

Any ideas please?

Comment: have you tried to overwrite the variable in php itself? i.e. somewhere at the top in your first php file: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = "live.mydomain.com";` (of course you have to decide when you should overwrite the variable and handle this case)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller That is indeed an option, but I do end up with split codebases again. Also, the system uses the gigantic Symfony framework, which I would have to hack into :-(

Comment: Personally, I use an optional config file, which is only used if present. the codebase itself stays the same and you can do some stuff in that special file. if you put this inclusion before the bootstrapper of the symfony framework, you should do fine.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller You answer was a good starting point for me, but I had to do a fair bit more to get it working. Details below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another 3 hours searching on the internet, I eventually found an answer. I'll leave it here for the next person searching how to do this.

First things first. `ModRewrite` was not the answer! By the time Apache is processing its `ModRewrite` and `SetEnv` settings, the `SERVER_NAME` and 'HTTP_HOST' variables are cast in stone. You can try resetting them, but your PHP won't ever see the changed values.

What does work is PHP's **auto_prepend** option. How you set this depends on your PHP setup, but the flag is as follows:

`auto_prepend_file=prepend.php`

Then create the `prepend.php` file in your document root:

`<?php
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'dev.mydomain.com'){
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']= 'live.mydomain.com';
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']= 'live.mydomain.com';
    }
?>`

It even works in Symfony. All you have to do is ensure the `prepend.php` file stays out of your master repository.

Comment: nice one. can you prepend multiple files for different domains? or do you use the same php file every time?

Comment: @RaphaelMüller: I'll be using the same PHP file for several domains, but there's no reason why someone couldn't include multiple php files from the prepend file.